# asp.net 32bit app cannot find 32bit ODBC driver on 64bit server

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, odbc, dns, 32-bit

I have a an asp.net app that uses a SYSTEM DSN, and it works fine on local machine. After deploying to a 64 Bit server I am unable to connect to the DB using the dsn.

Here is what I did,  I created the 32 bit system DSN on the server and it tested connection correctly ( created it under %WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe . The 64 bit DSN entry is empty (at %WINDIR%\System32\odbcad32.exe).

Now When I run the app it seems like it is trying to find the system dsn entry in the 64 bit ODBC driver instead of the 32 bit.

Is there a setting on the Odbc connection that will force it to look at 32 bit DSN entry ?Is there a server config that I need to change .I havealready set the app pool on iis to enable 32 bit apps , but it didnt help ..I have been banging my head on this for hrs , any help is appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some how you've got things mixed up. 32 bit apps look in one place for DSNs and 64 bit apps look in another place. You cannot mix 32 bit apps with 64 bit ODBC drivers (or vice versa) so it does not make sense for the setting you enquire about.

Comment: I have set the DNS entry in the %WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe and it does show up 32 DSN..what am i missing ?

Comment: OdbcException 
   ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified